# Can I speed up the queries of triangulation properties in matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab

I'm writing a MATLAB optimization code, and the code itself works, but I'll need to run it multiple times in another optimization process so I wanted to try and speed it up. Using the profiler I was able to detect that the slower parts of the program were all the "TR.Points(...)" and "TR.ConnectivityList(...)". Are these queries supposed to be this slow, or are there more efficient ways to call them?